# WSL: Am I running version 1 or version 2?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL), but I don't know which version I have, and many things won't work in version 1. How do I check my version?

Comment: @Rinzwind You are welcome to join with me requesting such at https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4555

Comment: From that thread, it looks like the following bash command works:
`uname -r | grep Microsoft > /dev/null && echo "WSL1"`. -- It's a pretty adhoc way to detect it, but it will print "WSL1" if that's what you're running.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 Extremely fragile but works for me! In WSL1, `uname -r` ends with `-Microsoft`, in WSL2, it ends `-microsoft-standard` ... lower case "m"!

Comment: @Rinzwind Any questions regarding WSL, including how to install it, are on-topic, in my opinion.

Comment: @Flimm not if the answer lies outside of wsl. As soon as someone mentions powershell it IS off topic We are NOT supposed to know anything that is a tool in Windows.

Comment: @Rinzwind If the question is on-topic, then so are the answers to that question. If someone asks how to create a bootable Ubuntu USB stick on Windows, then that question is on-topic, and so are all the answers to it, even if the answers mention unetbootin.exe . Same thing with WSL.

Comment: I would at least expect `wsl --version` to be available...

Comment: Check the File Version in the Details tab of the Properties of C:\Windows\System32\Wsl.exe - if it is less than 10.0.19041.x then it is WSL1.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

1. At a Windows 10 command prompt, run `ver`. Is the next-to-last numeric group version [18917 or higher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install)? If so, it is *possible* you have WSL 2 but not yet *verified*. Go on to step A *or* B.
   If you do *not* see Windows version 18917 or higher, you have version 1.
   This illustrates the result when the OS is Build 16299:

   [image: Version 16299]

   A. Open Windows **PowerShell** or **cmd** and enter the command `wsl -l -v`.  If version 2 is installed properly, you will see the version number. If you don't see a version number, or if you see an error message (Thank you, [Cornea Valentin](https://askubuntu.com/users/712582/cornea-valentin)) you have version 1 (you may also see a version number '1' which could indicate that you're running v1 - see [here](https://codefellows.github.io/setup-guide/windows/#verify-that-you-are-running-wsl-version-2)). Uninstall it then reinstall it as per https://scotch.io/bar-talk/trying-the-new-wsl-2-its-fast-windows-subsystem-for-linux

   B.  From the WSL shell prompt, run `uname` or `uname -r`. If the kernel version >= 4.19, it's WSL Version 2.

Why is this relevant?

WSL 1 was based on Microsoft's Linux-compatible kernel interface, a  [compatibility translation layer](https://mikegerwitz.com/2016/04/gnu-kwindows) with [no Linux kernel](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2019/05/07/windows-terminal-and-linux-kernels.aspx) code.

WSL 2 was redesigned with a Linux kernel running in a lightweight VM environment, and innovators have found many more things they can do with WSL 2.

Windows 10 Version 2004 (build 19041.153 & later) enhances WSL2 further; see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl2-will-be-generally-available-in-windows-10-version-2004/ and https://winaero.com/blog/wsl2-will-ship-with-windows-10-version-2004-with-kernel-updates-via-windows-update/ .

Comment: also if he get any errors after: wsl -l -v  it's 100%  wsl 1.

Comment: I needed to use uname -r to see the kernel version, but the kernel version ended up being 4.4.0, which I'm pretty sure means WSL 1.

Comment: Use `uname -a` to print kernel version.

Comment: For me, `wsl -l -v` prints the usage info (i.e. doesn't work), but `wsl -l --verbose` prints the verbose list as intended. `systeminfo.exe` gives me `OS Version: 10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041`.

Comment: According to [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and a [Microsoft blogger](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl-2-support-is-coming-to-windows-10-versions-1903-and-1909/#how-do-i-get-it), we can also get WSL2 on (1903 or 1909) build 18362.1049, due to a new backport. That helps those of us in companies that don't yet have build 18917, which is mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: I'm seeing 4.4, is that greater or less than 4.19?

Comment: In PS it is winver to see a popup with the Windows version

Comment: As of Dec 2020, typing `wsl -l -v` returns `VERSION 1` for me with `Ubuntu 20.04`. Nice fix for the newer Ubuntu v1. Cool!

Comment: The mentioned link at https://scotch.io was perfect

Comment: What if I see `Invalid command line option: -l`?

Comment: your answer contradicts itself - I am seeing a version number from the first test, suggesting it's version 2, but my kernel is lower than what you say is needed for version 2.

Answer (score 108):

1. Open PowerShell
2. Check the version with `wsl -l -v`
3. If at version 1, then update the version with `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2`

*Note: Changing the version of a running OS will terminate it.*
*The name of the OS need not be Ubuntu-20.04 for you. Please select the actual name listed in* `wsl -l -v`

If you are not able to update to version 2, then you may not be on the WSL 2 Kernel. This can be [downloaded from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel).

Comment: Note on point 3, running it will instantly kill currently running instances of the OS selected, eg all instances of Ubuntu-20.02 in this case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I added a note to point that out.

Comment: @Jack, Having only one version of ubuntu, 18.04, I noticed that "wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2" worked for me without specifying the version. I suspect that's always the case.

Comment: This is the correct answer for me on Windows 10.

Comment: Simply run `wsl --status` as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRW5r7TK6KM

Comment: `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2`
"There is no distribution with the supplied name."

Answer (score 8):

In the WSL version I was running, I just typed `uname -r` to which I got the result

`5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2`

So, I can say that its WSL2, so you can try running `uname -r` and check.

Comment: That will work as long as you are running the stock kernel, but it could be named differently if you use a custom kernel.  Also, for reference, WSL1 kernels are something like "4.4.0-22000-Microsoft" (without the "-standard-WSL2").  I seem to recall that 4.x releases on WSL2 were just "-microsoft-standard" (without the "-WSL2), but I could be wrong.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft (Server 2019 WSL 1)

Answer (score 4):

Programmatically:

```bsh
# Multiline 
wsl.exe -l -v |
iconv -f utf16 |
egrep "\b${WSL_DISTRO_NAME}\s+Running" |
tr -d '\r' |
sed 's/.*\([[:digit:]]\)[[:space:]]*/\1/'
```

Will return `1` or `2`.

Line-by-line, this:

- Executes `wsl.exe -l -v` to return the full list of all distributions you might have installed
- Runs it through `iconv` to fix its malformed UTF16 output.  You don't normally see the problem unless you try to grep it (or pipe it to something like `hexdump -C`), but you have to clean it up before you can grep it.
- Matches the current instance (via `$WSL_DISTRO_NAME`) line
- Removes the DOS line ending
- Finds the version number in the line and outputs it

Thanks to [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1628052/1210833) for the concept.

This will work as long as Interop is enabled for WSL.

If Interop isn't enabled, then a fallback method is to check `/proc/cmdline`:

- `/proc/cmdline` on WSL1 is `BOOT_IMAGE=/kernel init=/init`
- `/proc/cmdline` on WSL2 is `initrd=\initrd.img panic=-1 pty.legacy_count=0 nr_cpus=16`

So:

- `grep -q "^BOOT_IMAGE" /proc/cmdline` returns success on WSL1 but error on WSL2
- `grep -q "^initrd" /proc/cmdline` returns success on WSL2 but error on WSL1

This currently works (and has for the last year, at least), but could change in the future if either the WSL1 or WSL2 architecture changes in some way.  However, I expect that the `/proc/cmdline` is likely always going to differ between WSL1 and WSL2 and can be programmatically parsed to determine the current version.

Answer (score -1):

If you happen to be running Docker for Windows and you have WSL 1, then if you enter `docker` in the terminal for your WSL, you'll see the message `The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 1 distro.`, which is a very clear confirmation.