# WSL + integrated camera

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, camera, integrated

I have a Microsoft Surface tablet, Windows 10 and I run **Windows Subsystem for Linux with Ubuntu**.

I would like to know if WSL can access the **integrated** camera of my tablet.

All other articles/questions/other online resources I have come across only talk about WSL not accessing a **USB camera**, but none mention explicitly an **integrated camera.**

Requested info:
WSL version:
I have Microsoft Surface Pro 4 with Windows 10.
OS build is 18362 and I've tried wsl -l which fails. So, my understanding from these two is that I have WSL (v1)

```
xx@Surface:~$ sudo lspci && lsusb
[sudo] password for :
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
lspci: Cannot find any working access method.
```

Comment: Which verson of WSL are you using? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177729/wsl-am-i-running-version-1-or-version-2/1177730#1177730

Comment: Please do `sudo lspci && lsusb` and copy the results, then come back here, click [edit], and paste the results into your question, so we have a better understanding on whether the camera is a USB device or interfaces by PCI. Please do not use Add Comment.