# How to add to /etc/environment?

Tags: environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux, paths

I use a mac at work, which has /etc/paths to add paths, with the syntax:

/usr/foo

/usr/bar

Using wsl with ubuntu-18.04-ls, I wanted to add "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin" to etc/environment, because I read that is the equivalent of /etc/paths.
Changed the line from: `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

to

`PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`,restarted, typed echo $PATH but it would still print the old line. Am I in the wrong spot for setting paths globally or did I do something wrong?

Comment: yes, as written I did

Comment: How did you change the file? are you sure your changes were successfully saved? What do you see now if you `cat /etc/environment`?

Comment: Which version of WSL are you using? See https://askubuntu.com/a/1177730/197910

Comment: Just a thought... Why do you want to add a directory, specific to the `linuxbrew` user, to `PATH` globally? A more natural place to achieve your goal might be to edit `/home/linuxbrew/.profile`.

Comment: Using WSL 2.
Linuxbrew stated it is not in my PATH. Hence, I want to add it to my PATH. The other options I found would to add it to specific shells or profiles, which I would have to do separately for every shell or profile, from what I understood. I should be able to do it via Windows, but I want to get it working directly in Ubuntu.

Comment: cat /etc/environment prints like this PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"