# WSL Ubuntu app on Windows 10 closes immediately

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been using Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10 for a week. Today after a required system restart it stopped working. It closes soon after opened. I have turned off and back on the WSL feature but it didn't help.

Please let me know if this has a fix.

Comment: Sounds like a Windows update bug.  They normally send out updates on Tuesday/Wednesday.

Comment: This is a Windows issue; please consult our sister Q&A site https://superuser.com for Windows support. They will want to know which version of WSL you have; here's how to find out. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177729/wsl-am-i-running-version-1-or-version-2

Comment: What do you get if you run `ubuntu` in CMD? (The command can vary depending on the release you've installed. For example, `ubuntu1604` or `ubuntu1804` or simply `ubuntu`)

Answer (score 3):

This happened on my machine, too. After removing and installing Ubuntu completely again, I've noticed that a recent Docker installation caused that issue.

Checking with `wsl --list` from cmd.exe it showed me

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
docker-desktop-data (Default)
docker-desktop
Ubuntu
```

So I set the default back to Ubuntu with

```
wsl --set-default Ubuntu
```

Comment: didn't help in my case

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled Ubuntu and that seems to have fixed the problem. The original problem did start when I was required to restart for a Windows update on my system. After the update I started having the above issue in Ubuntu. Now after reinstallation, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case, I didn't have the `Ubuntu` distribution.

So, I installed it, using this command:

```bash
wsl --install -d Ubuntu
```

Then I used the following command to set the `Ubuntu` distribution as default:

```bash
wsl --set-default Ubuntu
```

Other useful commands:

```
# To list all installed distributions
wsl --list --verbose
wsl -l -v

# To see the available distributions to install
wls --list --online
```

More details about this issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6218#issuecomment-1329818462