# Making the installed packages in the WSL portable

Tags: apt, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there any way to port a program like [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) which is installed in the WSL to another windows machine without the need to open the linux terminal ?

Thank you,
Igor

Comment: Do you want to install a whole desktop environment suite in WSL ? If so why don't you install and use a full-featured ubuntu desktop in virtualbox or VMWare and use the shared-folder feature to move the files between them ?

Comment: The only thing I actually want to install is Apache Airflow, so I want to keep the Linux component as small as possible, using terminal works just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by terminal application ? Do you mean Command-line apps ? So what's the problem with apt-get install ?

Comment: There is no problem, apt-get install works just fine. What I want to do is to avoid using it when installing the environment (which is exactly the same) on other computers, people there may have no Linux experience at all. So my idea is: install it once, make sure it works and make some kind of image out of it, which can be distributed as a whole.

Comment: Each program that you install with apt spreads through different directories in the system. For example /usr/ , /etc/ , /var/ , etc. So it is difficult to copy and paste all of them . Also at the time of this writing , there's no program in windows to actually install .deb packages ( i.e the format of all downloaded apps via apt-get ) in the WSL. So it's not possible to install a linux program via the windows environment .

Comment: But your case is different , you want to install apache airflow which can be [installed via python pip](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/installation.html) so you can install it in your WSL and then copy all the files in the " ~/.local/lib/python-version/site-packages" folder and reuse it on another system. But notice that the python version should be the same , so if the ubuntu version on the second machine is different , that might cause problems.

Comment: I hoped there is another way. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I edited your question to be more specific and informative . If there's not any flaw in it and if it conveys what you wanted , please consider accepting it.

Comment: Which version of WSL is installed? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177729/wsl-am-i-running-version-1-or-version-2

Comment: WSL 2.0 is installed.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can install the [Apache Airflow via python pip](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/installation.html) in your WSL subsystem and then copy all the files in the `~/.local/lib/python[your_python_version]/site-packages` and then you can zip it in order to transfer to another computer.

But note that if the Ubuntu version in the WSL subsystem of the second machine is different , that might cause some problems. Just make sure that the python's minor version is the same since the compatibility between the different minor versions of python isn't guaranteed.

You might need to install [python-pip](https://www.tecmint.com/install-pip-in-linux/) first.

Note : I haven't do it myself but it should work at least on the paper.

If anybody has a better solution , I'm glad to hear.