# No Wifi Connection on Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL1

Tags: wireless, indicator, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I install Ubuntu 18.04 running from Windows 10 (not Dual-boot). However, there is no Wifi option (on Desktop top right, or bottom  right corner).

Also, when I click on Network Connections, it does not respond. When I search for 'WiFi', it does not seem installed which is weird!

Any guidance would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you have WSL1 or WSL2? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177729/wsl-am-i-running-version-1-or-version-2

Comment: It seems I have WSL version 1 on Ubuntu 18.04. Does updating it to 2 help? can you share the procedure as how to remove old one and install new one. Thanks
Note: I was using Ubuntu 20.04 but becuase GNS3 does not work on it, I had to go back to 18.

Comment: Check your Windows version as described in the link provided above.

Comment: It is Version 1909. yesterday version 2004 was released but not to all PC-type vendors. My laptop is Lenovo. I tried to update it but 2004 is still not available.

Comment: Any suggestions K7AAY? as I need  to have Ubuntu up & running to have WiFi connection working and use GNS3

Comment: Unless you are in the Windows Insider program, right now you do not have access to WSL2, so you have WSL1. The link to WSL1 vs WSL2 explains eligibility based on the five digit build numbers, not the four digit release numbers. WSL1 is severely cripped by comparison to WSL2, and I would not use GNS3 on WSL1.

Comment: So, the only solution for now is to install a separate Linux (dual boot)? to have it running properly with GNS3

Comment: GNS3 was installed using Ubuntu command line but when I run it, it requires Internet connection  (WiFi) inside Linux environment to download & install VMWare and this is where I am struggling in right now!

Answer (score 0):

You can't run VMware inside WSL1 or WSL2. If you don't want to do a dual boot install (harmless), then make a Linux LiveUSB with persistence and install it on the LiveUSB (which will be slow).

Download [Ubuntu's 19.10 or 20.04 ISO file](https://ubuntu.com/download) or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .

Next, [check for download errors](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu)

Make a LiveUSB with persistence [following these instructions](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) on your Windows PC using the Windows [Rufus Open Source app](https://rufus.ie) to provide persistence, so you can subsequently iinstall GNS3 and its VMware payload.