# Error message "Wrong __data_start/_end pair" while using mpb in Ubuntu 20.04 Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed mpb in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Windows Subsystem for Linux using the command

```
sudo apt-get install mpb h5utils
```

When I tried to run the .ctl file, I got this error message:

```
Wrong __data_start/_end pair

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anyone help me to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly the same problem.
Upgrading WSL from version 1 to version 2 seems to have fixed it.

1. Follow steps 2-5 from the official upgrade instructions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10
2. Update your existing installations to WSL version 2 as follows:

   1. Start a powershell as admin
   2. Run `wsl -l -v` to check your versions and installations. Example output:

   ```
   PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl -l -v
   NAME            STATE           VERSION
   * Ubuntu-18.04    Stopped         1
   Ubuntu-20.04    Stopped         1
   ```

   3. Upgrade with `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2`. Example:

   ```
   PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2
   Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
   For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
   Conversion complete.
   ```

If you get this error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
The requested operation could not be completed due to a virtual disk system limitation.  Virtual hard disk files must be uncompressed and unencrypted and must not be sparse.
```

1. Go to the Ubuntu directory in your profile folder (something like %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited...).
2. Right click on "LocalState", Properties, Advanced
3. Deselect "Compress contents" (and I suppose "Encrypt contents" as well if that's checked).
4. When it asks whether you want to apply to just this folder or to all subfolders and files, you can say "just this folder", because all you're doing is clearing that "compress" flag. After that the wsl --set-version command should work.

Finally, check your WSL version: [WSL: Am I running version 1 or version 2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177729/wsl-am-i-running-version-1-or-version-2)

References:

- https://dev.to/wrightdotclick/20x-faster-speeds-by-updating-to-the-new-wsl-2-a-user-s-installation-guide-57n4
- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4103

Answer (score 0):

As I'm running Windows Server 2019, upgrading to WSL 2 was not an practical option.
So I recompiled zile 2.6.1 from the sources. I had to install several dependencies but in the end, it worked fine.

Here are the commands to install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt install gcc
sudo apt install pkgconf
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libgee-0.8*
sudo apt install curses
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
sudo apt install make
sudo apt install help2man
```

then the usuals:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```