# Unable to upgrade to wsl 2

Tags: upgrade, windows-subsystem-for-linux

A while back I installed WSL by following the instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). I was under the impression that I was running WSL 2. However, when I launched `code-insiders` from the terminal (Ubuntu 20.04) today, I got a message saying that I'm running WSL 1 and strongly recommended that I upgrade. This was a surprise to me because I didn't think I was running WSL 1. Anyway, I opened a power shell (without admin) and ran `wsl -l -v` and confirmed that I was in fact running WSL 1.

So I followed the instructions in that link again and after all the installs I ran `wsl --set-default-version 2` and was greeted with a "The operation completed successfully" message. However, even after this, when I check the version, I still see I'm running WSL 1 and `code-insiders` still has the same message about the WSL version. I'm not sure what's wrong here and any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a Windows question.

Comment: I saw this https://askubuntu.com/q/1177729/193533 question here, so I posted mine. Where should I post this question then?

Comment: @ChanganAuto WSL is on-topic

Comment: @Nmath is changing the WSL operating format on the Windows configuration side of things on topic though?  While WSL itself and issues within WSL may be on topic, I'm not so sure about the windows configuration side of things.

Comment: @shaun Just because you set the default version to version 2 doesn't mean your WSL install has been converted to WSL 2 - you just changed the default for future WSL installs is all.  Get your distro list with `wsl --list --verbose` in PowerShell on Windows host.  Set the thing to WSL2 - `wsl --set-version <Distro> 2`  (replace Distro)

Comment: @ThomasWard While I fully agree that [Super User](https://superuser.com) would definitely be a *better* place for this, the problem (IMHO) is that (a) we can't expect the person asking the question to necessarily know if the problem is on the Ubuntu side, the Windows side, or a combination of both.  (b) Often (not in this case) there *is* some Ubuntu-specific knowledge that will help.  In this case, however, it's moot, because the answer is in the very question that the OP linked to in a comment, making it an obvious duplicate, IMHO.

Comment: @shaun Note that ThomasWard's solution in the comments above is 100% correct, but it's also the same as is listed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1267099/1165986) of the question that you linked to in the comment above.  Please make sure you read through the existing answers of similar questions before posting a duplicate!  Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WSL: Am I running version 1 or version 2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177729/wsl-am-i-running-version-1-or-version-2)

Comment: @ThomasWard your comment helped me resolve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Apologies! I didn't scroll down far enough after the accepted answer.

Comment: @shaun No worries - Just go ahead and accept the suggestion and it should auto-close as a duplicate.  Thanks!